# MVC2 Ajax autocomplete using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to implement Ajax autocomplete in MVC2 and having no success. It is not getting into the autocomplete. Can you tell me what is wrong? Here is my script.

```
             $('#Contact').change(function () {
                  debugger;
                  $('#Contact').autocomplete({

                      source: function (request, response) {
                          $.ajax({
                              url: "/ChapterRelationship/GetContacts",
                              data: {searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10},
                              type: "POST", // http method 
                              datatype: "json",
                              success: function (msg) {
                                  // ajax call has returned 
                                  var result = msg;
                                  var a = [];
                                  if (result !== null) {
                                      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                          a.push({ label: result[i].prop1, id: result[i].prop2 });
                                      } 
                                  } responseFn(a);
                              } 
                          });
                      } 
                  });
              });
```

Here is my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult  GetContacts(string id)
    {
       // return Content("test");
        return this.Json("test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly complete sample of MVC2 and jQuery autocomplete:

http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.com/2010/03/jquery-autocomplete-with-aspnet-mvc.html

I'm not sure you've provided enough code to give a more complete answer, although someone else may be able to spot the issue without complete code.